# Populate List<Object> from ResultSet without creating new Object for each dataset

Tags: java, list, jdbc, resultset

I have been always using the following code to add Objects from a ResultSet into a List. However someone commented that it is not very efficient to create a new Object for every dataset in the ResultSet. Is there a better way? Or, is there a whole different way to add Object from a ResultSet to a List?

```
public static List<Students> selectFromDatabase(Connection conn, Statement stmt){
    List<Students> list = new ArrayList<Students>();
    String select = "SELECT * FROM students";
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);

        while(rs.next()){
            //you have to create a new OBJECT FOR EACH LOOP
            Students student = new Students();
            student.setStudentId(rs.getInt(1));
            student.setName(rs.getString(2));
            student.setGpa(rs.getInt(3));
            list.add(student);
        }               
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
    return list;
}
```

Comment: "Someone" has no clue of what he/she's talking about. Just ignore him/her. What you should do, though, is rename Students to Student, remove the stmt argument which makes no sense, stop using `select *` and list the actual columns you want, stop catching and ignoring SQLExceptions, and use try-with-resources to make sure the statement is closed. In short, there are many things to change in this code, but "Someone" only suggested to change the part that has no preoblem.

Comment: @StamatiaCh how will the resultset know what type is the object associated ?

Comment: Some code **has** to create the Objects

Comment: +1 for @JBNizet, and no offense you should asked that "someone" what his/her opinion in this matter, because sooner or later you have to create that object, somewhere in ur code, there is a reason why it;s called OBJECT Oriented !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on your OP have pretty much already answered your question, I'll just provide some extra insight.

You have a `List` that contains `Students` objects. You populate this `List` by creating a `Students` object and adding that object to the `List` for every result that's in `rs`. How would you go about doing this if you just made one `Students` object? You've gotta make as many objects as there are results in `rs` in order to do what it is you're trying to do. This is pretty much what always happens with these data structures, unless it's an array.

Answer (score -1):

that someone is right at some cost of heavy coding. It is not really needed to create a new object . you can always use the same student object and use set to new values and add to list. Sorry I was about to same object with different references....! Copy pasted and missed to add the code inside the loop ! The edited is was i meant

```
public static List<Students> selectFromDatabase(Connection conn, Statement stmt){
    List<Students> list = new ArrayList<Students>();
    String select = "SELECT * FROM students";
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
        Students student = null;
        while(rs.next()){
                student = new Students();
            //you have to create a new OBJECT FOR EACH LOOP            
            student.setStudentId(rs.getInt(1));
            student.setName(rs.getString(2));
            student.setGpa(rs.getInt(3));
            list.add(student);
        }               
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
    return list;
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. The list would containg N references to the same object, containing the information about the last student in the resultset.

Comment: Sorry .. I edited the code now.. I was trying to meniton that same object with different references...! Hope this makes sense....

Comment: Yeah, that's the same code as the OP: it creates as many Student objects. You just made it a bit worse by declaring the student variable in a scope that is larger than it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @JB Nizet ... Now understood my mistake.. I just did the same what is done in the question ! Didnt realise it first time..!